# YAML Exception - Cannot read an implicit mapping pair

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless, bad-request

Exception while doing `replaceAll`

Y A M L Exception

```
can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed in "/home/serverless.yml" at line 144, column 99: ... ($input.body).replaceAll("\\'","'")"}'
```

Section of `serverless.yml` , which throws error

```
      request:
        template:
           application/json: '{"body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\'","'")"}'
           application/xml: '{"body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\'","'")"}'
           text/xml: '{"body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\'","'")"}'
      response:
        statusCodes:
          200:
            pattern: ''
            template:
              application/xml: '#set ($bodyObj = $util.parseJson($input.body)) $bodyObj'
          400:
            pattern: '400'
        headers:
          Content-Type: "'application/xml'"
```

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
template:[enter image description here][1]
       application/json: '{"body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\'","'")"}'
```

is invalid YAML for various reasons.

- Your `template:[enter image description here][1]` is a scalar and then on the second line you start a mapping. Scalars are always leaf nodes in the YAML datastructure. Not sure what you actually want to do there.
- In

  ```
  '{"body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\'","'")"}'
  ```

  you  should escape the single quotes withing the scalar:

  ```
  '{"body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\''","''")"}'
  ```

Comment: Thanks Anton , This -  template:[enter image description here][1] , i was actually trying to insert an image , hence it got added automatically while posting to Stack overflow.

Comment: and i'll try this format - '{"body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\''","''")"}' and update.

Comment: This format - '{"body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body).replaceAll("\\''","''")"}'  , although did not create issue during lambda deployment , but yet did not solve the purpose. I want to escape ' coming in my request.  Request has this tag --> <GivanName>Nai'Mei</GivenName>. I want to escape this single quote , that comes after Nai and before Mei.  AWS documentation has this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html --> Accessing the $util Variable (go to this section) - check the util implenmentation

Comment: I have no idea why you quote the whole mapping and not just the value (with only single quotes) whereas the AWS documentation doesn't seem to do that.